# PHP: Access tokens stored in session variables lost on form submission

Tags: php, forms, session, post, oauth

I've stored certain credentials like the OAuth Secret and OAuth Token Secret obtained from the Twitter OAuth provider inside session variables are follows:

```
$_SESSION['o_token'] = $access_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['o_token_secret'] = $access_token['oauth_token_secret'];
```

To make sure that the access tokens are indeed being stored inside my session variables, I tried echoing them on the screen before submitting my form, and as expected, the tokens were displayed.

Now, I have a form, and on submitting the form, the access tokens stored inside my session variables are lost. When I try echoing out something like this after submitting my form:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {
        echo $_SESSION['o_token'];
    }
```

nothing gets displayed, because the value stored inside `$_SESSION['o_token']` is now empty.

While are the access token data stored inside my session variables lost after form submission?

PS: In order to confirm that only the access token data is lost on form submission and not the other session variable data, I tried defining a mock session variable:

```
$_SESSION['mock'] = "mock";
```

and then tried echoing it after form submission:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {
        echo $_SESSION['mock'];
    }
```

The above code does display `mock`, which means that ONLY the access token data stored inside session variables is lost.

What seems to be wrong here?

EDIT: Yes, I have included `session_start()` at the start of my code.

Comment: are you calling `session_start()` at the top of every page?

Answer (score 0):

you said that you echo session , that means you've already put session start at the beginning of page .

check your post input value  which you filled by session variable

Comment: Yes, I can echo the post input value which I stored in another session variable.

Comment: did you check the target page? is session start also being there?

Comment: The target page is the same page itself. The page refreshes after form submission.

Answer (score 0):

an other thing you can do, is pass the token via form if you don't want to call session_start() and of course if it does not pose any security risk

```
<input type="hidden" name="acces_token" value="<?= $_SESSION['o_token']?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="o_token_secret" value="<?= $_SESSION['o_token_secret']?>" />
```

the values should be in the `$_POST` array. Hope this help.

Comment: When I tried inspecting the form element, this is what I got from the source code: `<input type="hidden" name="o_token" value="">` for a text field that I defined as follows: `<input type="hidden" name="o_token" value="<?php echo $access_token['oauth_token']; ?>" />`. The value is empty for the hidden text fields.

Comment: you want to echo `$_SESSION['access_token']` not `$access_token['oauth_token']`

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem either. The value of the hidden text field is still empty.

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi you said "To make sure that the access tokens are indeed being stored inside my session variables, I tried echoing them on the screen before submitting my form, and as expected, the tokens were displayed"  ?????

Comment: They are being displayed when I try to display them BEFORE submitting my form. However, AFTER submitting the form, those variables are lost.

Comment: something is not right, if you can be echo them out then inputs should have a value.

Comment: Sometimes, I also get a `Uncaught exception 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthException'` exception thrown. Is it a library issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87749/discussion-between-mdamia-and-manas-chaturvedi).